# mysql-server installation stuck in docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, docker

In my `Dockerfile` I have command for installing `mysql-server`:

```
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

The problem occurs when I type root password. I press enter and nothing happens and installation is stuck.

[image]

Comment: IIRC a Dockerfile isn’t supposed to be interactive. It simply must not ask for a password.

Comment: I solved it by using `docker-mysql` image and `docker-compose` where I connected multiple images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install mysql on Docker could be complex. You can use some of the existing resources, for example this:

https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-mysql

You can find a Dockerfile with a nice entrypoint file too.

There, you also can find the documentation about how to build and run the container.

Answer (score 1):

## Installtion Process of MySql in a Docker Container

The default CentOS container does not contain systemd, so the typical strategy for beginning/ceasing administrations (systemctl) doesn't work.

Basically, you have to do the accompanying. I'm utilizing official mysql rather than mariadb.

## add the official mysql rpm repo

wget -q http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
yum -y update

## install mysql

yum -y install mysql-server

## create mysql database files

mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql

## Start mysql as a background process using the “mysql” user account

su mysql -c /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &

## Optional: set mysql root password

/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'rootpass'

Hope this would be helpful for you..

Comment: You could be a little more precise, like providing the exact commands which will be in the Dockerfile. Like: RUN yum -y install mysql-server